# Declaring object in header file C++

Tags: c++, oop, class, header

I have declared a class in a header file (.h), and I defined its constructor and functions (including default constructor) in a .cpp

Now I want to declare an object in another header file, and initialize it in another .cpp file. I need to do it like this because the initialization of the object depends on some variables in the cpp.
The declaration in the .h file is made like this:

```
Saboteur *activeFault; /*Saboteur is the class, activeFault the object*/
```

When I try to compile my program I get the following error:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'.

Any clue why this happens??

Hint: #includes are all ok, and the most strange thing is that I get the error when the compiler tries to compile the .cpp file where the functions of the `class Saboteur` are defined, but it says that the error is in the line written above (which is the other cpp file).

Comment: Looks like the compiler has not yet seen the definition of `Saboteur` when it processes this line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prototype the Saboteur class. Declare:

```
class Saboteur;
```

before that declaration of `activeFault`.

Then, in other place, you provide the full definition of `class Saboteur`.

Comment: Ok thanks, that works, but why do I have to prototype it? I mean, I have the include to the header with the declaration of the classes in the beginning of the file, I don´t understand why I need to do that.

Comment: @Iban: If you have included a header that declares the class, then you shouldn't need another declaration. But it sounds like you haven't included it. Perhaps you have two headers both trying to include each other?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Sometimes I'm stumbling over include-guards that were copied from another .h file and werent changed in the copy. This might lead to such effect ...

Comment: Ok, that might be the problem, since I have a header file with lots of includes, and I include that file in almost all the header files I have, because they have a lot of relationships between them. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Iban if this solves your problem, then you should seriously tidy up your include structure. You should not have to both include a class' header and forward declare the class.

Comment: @Iban you are simply informing the compiler that the *Saboteur* word is an identifier for a later-to-be-defined class. Since, given your code, the compiler knows nothing about the word *Saboteur* when it stumbles upon, it simply considers it a typing error.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for the advice, I tidyed up the project and now it is working without the need of prototyping the class.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ideas that come to mind

1. Did you include the .h file of the Saboteur in the header file
   producing this problem?
2. is this a templated class?
3. maybe the header
   file including the saboteur is included before actually including
   the saboteur class. in this case add in your other .h file:

   class Saboteur;